# Making subversion "update if already checked out, check out otherwise"

Tags: shell, svn, automation, svn-checkout

I want to write this script which goes into a directory that usually contains a checked-out subversion repository, and updates it; it should also checkout the repo if it's missing for some reason. Is there some special svn command to do this, or should I resort to checking whether .svn exists?

Answer (score 1):

> checking whether .svn exists

Isn't bullet-proof method (in case of possible future changes)

Check output of `svnversion` or `svn info` in unversioned directory seems more promising

Comment: So something like `RESULT=\`svn info | grep "not a working copy"\`; if [[ -n $RESULT ]]; then svn co $MYPROJECT; fi` ?

Comment: @einpoklum - I'm too lazy to read you bashisms, but - yes... something like it, while I personally prefer the brevity of  `grep -q &&`